# How to maintain the aspect ratio of the UIImage placed at the top to the view?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode8

In storyboard i am placing an UIImageView for the purpose of placing the profile picture. So this image is entirely at the top of the UIView.For this i have set the constraints like this:

[image: Contraints for UIImageView in SE]

Preview in iPhone7:

[image]

Preview in iPhone7plus:
[image]

The problem is that though the UIImage is correctly placed at the top centre but it is not growing in size as the screen size increases. So i think i need to reset the UIImage constraints for that . How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have set explicit constraints for height and width to each be 100.

What I would suggest is making a constraint which sets the width of your image view to be equal to the width of the main view. Then set the multiplier on that constraint to be something like .25 (or whatever works best for you). This will make the width of your image view always be 25% of the width of the view, so it will be larger on larger devices. Like so:

[image: Proportional Width constraint]

After setting that constraint, you should add an aspect ratio constraint for the image view (drag across the image view and let go, the select "Aspect Ratio"). Set that multiplier to be 1:1 and your image view will be a square.

[image: Aspect Ratio Constraint]

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of how to set this constraints. I am new to the multipliers